# Android Radio Buttons not Themed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

I'm having problems understanding why my theme in `style.xml` is not being applied consistently. I am putting RadioButtons in a RadioGroup programmatically inside a fragment.  The RadioGroup is defined in XML.  Regardless of what I set in `style.xml` my selected button has a black center.  If I create a new project, define the group and two buttons in XML in a regular activity, and apply the same theme then the selected button is whatever my `colorAccent` is set to instead of black.

Here's the code that builds my RadioGroup programmatically

```
public class MainDataSelectionFragrment extends Fragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainDataSelectionFragrment";
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mCallback;

    private TextView welcome;
    private Spinner schoolList;
    private String schoolCode = "";
    private RadioGroup terms;
    private String termSelected = "";
    private Spinner dataTypes;
    private String dataTypeSelected = "";
    private Spinner subjects;
    private String subjectSelected = "";
    private Button search;
    private TermsAsyncTask termsAsyncTask;

    public MainDataSelectionFragrment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // track this view so that we can find views inside it
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_data_selection, container, false);

        // views inside this one that will be modified in some way
        this.welcome = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_welcome);
        this.schoolList = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_school_list);
        this.terms = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rg_terms);
        this.dataTypes = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_data_type);
        this.subjects = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_subjects);
        this.search = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

        // assign listeners
        this.onItemSelectedListenerForSchoolsSpinner();
        this.setOnCheckedChangeListenerForTerm();
        this.onItemSelectedListenerForDataTypesSpinner();
        this.voidOnItemSelectedListenerForSubjectsSpinner();
        this.onClickListenerForSearchButton();

        // Register with the bus
        OttoBus.getInstance().register(this);

        // return this view
        return rootView;
    }


    private void buildTermsRadioGroup(ArrayList<String> terms) {

        // create new buttons and add them to the group
        for (String term : terms) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating RadioButton for " + term);

            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());

            radioButton.setText(StringUtils.capitalize(term));

            radioButton.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

            this.terms.addView(radioButton);
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1**
In response to comments: yes, I am using AppCompat-v7

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!-- customize the color palette -->

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
            colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar / ToolBar styles -->
    <style name="AppBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- android:textColorPrimary is the  color of the title text
            in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/bar_textColorPrimary</item>

        <!-- android:textColorPrimaryInverse is the  color of the title
       text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme:  -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/bar_textColorPrimaryInverse</item>

        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/bar_textColorPrimary</item>
        <!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu
             overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/bar_textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You mention `colorAccent`. Are you using `appcompat-v7`? Or are you referring to native Android 5.0 `Theme.Material`-based coloring?

Comment: Please also include the relevant lines of your style and theme XML.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember... I haven't done android coding in a long time. Sorry.